# WPF MVVM Thread keep running and show progress in wpf windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Now i am developing background downloading application in WPF MVVM. When application start, the downloading thread is start working. I want to show downloading status in every WPF window's Label box to know how many percentage had been downloaded.

I already tried `BackgroundWorker`. I used HttpClient to download the file and dowloading process is written under `DoWork` function.

How can i get the download progress from every WPF windows for showing in Label box?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Best Rgds,
dartfrog

Comment: While backgroundworker is ok you might want to use some other ways to achieve asynchronicity, namely `Task`.

Comment: do you mean Task process in DoWork function?

Comment: How can i get the download progress from every WPF windows for showing in Label box? Are their multiple windows and one parent window with Label to see downloading status ? Or there are multiple downloading tasks within same window. This same window contains Label too. Please clarify.

Comment: cause downloading thread is keep running until the application exit. i want to show different windows got different style. that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `BackgroundWorker` or maybe `Task` to achieve this. What @razor118 said is true; download service should be singleton or preferably injected to your ViewModels and exposing an event is what you need here.

Here's (working but far from complete) example for you, using `Task`s and `EventHandler` to "notify" two separate `Window`s of download progress.

[image: imgur]

---

**App.xaml**

```
// where util is xmlns:util="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Util"
// Make file downloader a application level resource
<Application.Resources>
    <util:Downloader x:Key="MyDownloader" />
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <!-- MainView's data context -->
    <viewModel:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<!-- Label to show download progress -->
<Label Content="{Binding Progress}">
    <Label.ContentStringFormat>{0}%</Label.ContentStringFormat>
</Label>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Nothing to do here
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _progress;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // Open new window beside Main
        var otherView = new OtherWindow();
        otherView.Show();

        // Get downloader resource
        var downloader = Application.Current.Resources["MyDownloader"] as Downloader;
        // Update property when ever download progress changes (event)
        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => 
            Progress = args.ProgressPercentage;
        // Start downloading a 10Mb file
        downloader.Get("http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test");
    }

    public int Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        private set { _progress = value; RaisePropertyChanged();}
    }
}
```

**OtherWindow.xaml** (no backing ViewModel)

```
<!-- Label to show download progress -->
<Label x:Name="ProgressLabel"></Label>
```

**OtherWindow.cs**

```
public partial class OtherWindow : Window
{
    public OtherWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Get downloader resource
        var downloader = Application.Current.Resources["MyDownloader"] as Downloader;
        // Update label when ever download progress changes (event)
        downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => 
            ProgressLabel.Content = string.Format("{0}%", args.ProgressPercentage);
    }
}
```

**Downloader.cs**

```
public class Downloader // in WpfApplication.Util namespace
{
    public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> DownloadProgressChanged;

    // Download a file
    public async void Get(string url)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => OnProgressChanged(args);
            await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
        }
    }

    // Notify when progress changes
    private void OnProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = DownloadProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            DownloadProgressChanged(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bro, my download process return userid and download percentage. i got datagridview and populated with list of user. how can i show the specific row download process that filter by userid. my download is one at a time.

Comment: Maybe you should open another question about that. With your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way will be if you write custom class for this particular task (FileFetcher.cs) that will run task in background thread. This should be injected or be a singleton. Class could expose a event like: StatusChanged (with message for example "downlaoding 2 files 50%").

Each view can register for that event and update window labels after dispatching on UIThread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, razor118. did you get any example link or source code. cause i am quite noob on it.